# redirect to a custom page

Tags: plugins, php, woocommerce-offtopic, redirect, wp-redirect

i have created a plugin.
the plugin replace the add to cart button, to popup with continue botton.for every product that the shop owner choose.
i want that to redirect the user to my custom page when the button is clicked.
and i need that the page will display diffrent thing for diffrent product id.
where do i put the page in my plugin folder?

how to i redirect to it ?

i need that the page will use the shop theme, for example i want that the page will display the product page as is, by getting the product id in the url …

the code is the function that replace the button by id.

```
function replacing_add_to_cart_button( $button, $product  ) {
  $product_id = $product->get_id();
  //
  global $wpdb;

  $shopName = getShopName();
  $existQuary = "SELECT * FROM `wp_onePlusOne` WHERE `id` = '$product_id'";
  $existQuaryRes = $wpdb->get_results($existQuary);//simplafy query
  if(!empty($existQuaryRes)){

    $id_onePlusOne = get_object_vars($existQuaryRes[0])['id'];
    $button_text = __("1+1", "woocommerce");
    $button ="<div>".$button."
    <button id='myBtn".$id_onePlusOne."' onclick='display".$id_onePlusOne."()'>1+1</button>
      <div id='myModal".$id_onePlusOne."' class='modal'>
        <div class='modal-content".$id_onePlusOne."'>
          <span id='close".$id_onePlusOne."' class='close".$id_onePlusOne."'  onclick='spanDisplay".$id_onePlusOne."()'>&times;</span>
          <p id='".$id_onePlusOne."'><a href='http://linlRedirectTo."/".$id_onePlusOne."'  onclick='unDisplay".$id_onePlusOne."()' target='_blank'>" . $button_text . '</a>'  ."</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <style>
      .modal {
          display: none;
          position: fixed;
          z-index: 1;
          padding-top: 100px;
          left: 0;
          top: 0;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          overflow: auto;
          background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
          background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
      }
      .modal-content".$id_onePlusOne." {
          background-color: #fefefe;
          margin: auto;
          padding: 20px;
          border: 1px solid #888;
          width: 80%;
      }
      .close".$id_onePlusOne." {
          color: #aaaaaa;
          float: right;
          font-size: 28px;
          font-weight: bold;
      }
      .close".$id_onePlusOne.":hover,
      .close".$id_onePlusOne.":focus {
          color: #000;
          text-decoration: none;
          cursor: pointer;
      }
      </style>
    <script>
    function display".$id_onePlusOne."() {
        document.getElementById('myModal".$id_onePlusOne."').style.display = 'block';
    }
    function unDisplay".$id_onePlusOne."() {
        document.getElementById('myModal".$id_onePlusOne."').style.display = 'none';
    }
    function spanDisplay".$id_onePlusOne."() {
        document.getElementById('myModal".$id_onePlusOne."').style.display = 'none';
    }
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == document.getElementById('myModal".$id_onePlusOne."')) {
            document.getElementById('myModal".$id_onePlusOne."').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
    </script></div>" ;
  }

  return $button;

}
```

thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the template_include filter that will change the usual template for your redirect link. You can also mix it with template_redirect action.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include

Comment: that might work. but few more questions:
1.how can i connect that code to a specific button?
2.i need to send an id param with the url so the page will reload diffrent products how to do it?